# Need module for using 'ngb-tooltip-window' component (not directive)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

This is part of my code.

```
// my.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyComponent } from './sample/my.component';
import { MyRoutingModule } from './my-routing.module';
import { NgbTooltipModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbTooltipWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    NgbTooltipWindow
  ],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

```html
<!-- my.component.html -->
<ngb-tooltip-window role="tooltip" id="ngb-tooltip" class="tooltip show bs-tooltip-bottom">
   <div class="name"></div>
   <div class="age"></div>
</ngb-tooltip-window>
```

Result is this.

```sh
1. If 'ngb-tooltip-window' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tooltip-window' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

(Of course I did 2, but it doesn't works)

I need to use `<ngb-tooltip-window>`, but I don't know modules that I need.
I import `NgbTooltipModule`, `NgbTooltipWindow` but it doesn't works.
I also do googling but almost result use tooltip-window as directive. **I must use tooltp-window as component.**

Answer (score 0):

### I solved it... Only import module.

#### Before.

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    NgbTooltipWindow // X
  ],
```

#### Solved.

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbTooltipModule, // O
  ],
```